# What type of instance can django.conf.urls.url() be counted as?

Tags: python, django, url

While reading the official Django documentation, specifically the chapter 'URL dispatcher' about how Django processes requests, I stumbled upon something which made me uncertain.

The docs stated that the variable 'urlpatterns' is a list containing django.conf.urls.url() instances.

This made me wonder, is django.conf.urls.url(), or url() as commonly written within the framework, a function or a class? I have understood that everything in Python can be considered a class, however is it syntactically speaking a function or a class?

My first instinct was to research the django.conf.urls.url(), url(), within the Django documentation, but I was unable to find much to read.

This same question has now become relevant for me regarding other functions/classes that Django provides.

How can you be sure whether or not foo() is a function or a class? From my understanding, these are definitely functions, but I am having a hard time expressing why.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/conf.py); `url()` is a function that returns a Pattern instance.

In any case, Django follows pep8, so anything starting with a lower case letter is a function not a class.